# Swift - variable with type equal to protocol

Tags: swift, class, variables, protocols

If I:
1. Create a protocol.
2. Create a class which conforms to said protocol.
3. Instantiate said class.
4. Create a new variable = to said instance, making this variable's type = to the protocol.

Why is said new variable only able to perform the protocol function and not any other functions belonging to the class?

Comment: It can. Just cast it to the needed type

Comment: any instance has access to members(methods/properties) belonging to its declaring type (protocol in this case), if you want to access the members of the class the instance type must be of class. So cast it to class type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following:

```
protocol SomeProtocol {
    func doSomething()
}

class ClassOne: SomeProtocol {
    func doSomething(){
        print("did something!")   
    }
    func myStuff(){
        print("I'm not a part of the protocol")
    }
}
class ClassTwo: SomeProtocol {
    func doSomething(){
        print("did something too!")
    }
    func otherStuff(){
        print("I do other stuff that's not part of the protocol")
    }
}

var a: SomeProtocol = ClassOne()
a.doSomething()

//a.myStuff() //this will not compile
(a as? ClassOne)?.myStuff() //this compiles and will execute

a = ClassTwo()

a.doSomething() //this works too
(a as? ClassOne)?.myStuff() //compiles but cast will fail at runtime, so func doesn't execute
(a as? ClassTwo)?.otherStuff() //executes
```

When executed, this will output:

> did something!
>
> I'm not a part of the protocol
>
> did something too!
>
> I do other stuff that's not part of the protocol

Basically, if you declare that the variable only has to conform to the protocol, there's nothing to stop you from assigning an instance of a different class, as long as it conforms to the protocol.
As you can see above, you can cast it to the appropriate class whenever you need to and, provided it's an instance of that class, you will be able to access its properties and methods.

Comment: Thanks. Why do I have to cast it? i.e. fundamentally why is it that making the underlying class conform to the protocol - i.e. making it of type protocol - doesn't restrict use of its methods by an instance but when you make said instance (the variable to which it's been assigned) of type protocol there is this restriction.

Comment: When you declare that the variable conforms to the protocol, that's the only guarantee that the compiler has: any property/func of that protocol will be available on that instance. The fact that above we choose to instantiate `a` with `ClassOne` doesn't guarantee that `a` will always be an instance of `ClassOne`. The only guarantee is that it conforms to the protocol. It's tempting to think "But I've just instantiated it to a certain class, the compiler should know the actual class being used!" but in real life scenarios there could other threads changing the instance for example.